# How can I stop apps I do to not want appearing in the dock?

Tags: macos, dock, preferences

I have got into system preferences and there is no recents uncheck. How do I stop app icons from sticking in the dock?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is. See the last item in System preferences -> Dock.

[image: System preferences -> Dock Screenshot]